# Counting substrings in string

Tags: python-3.x

Lets assume that i have 2 strings

```
M = "sses"
N = "assesses"
```

I have to count how many times string M is present into string N

I am not allowed to use any import or methods just loops and range() if needed.

```
M = "sses"
N = "assesses"
counter = 0
if M in N:
  counter +=1
print(counter)
```

This isn't good enough i need loop to go trough N and count all M present
in this case it is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def count(M, N):
    i = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        try:
            i = N.index(M, i)+1
            count += 1
        except ValueError:
            break
    return count
```

Or a one-liner without `str.index`:

```
def count(M, N):
    return sum(N[i:i+len(M)]==M for i in range(len(N)-len(M)+1))
```

The same without using the `sum` function:

```
def count(M, N):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(N)-len(M)+1):
        if N[i:i+len(M)] == M:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: this is bit too advanced for me to use, we haven't gone yet trough some of the stuff(try:, .index, ValueError, sum) you use. We are allowed just loops and range()

Comment: thanks, now it is simple enough for me :-). Have to go trough it few times to understand what it does.